# efeito :hover e :active para imagem

Tags: html, css, css-hover

Como podem ver no código abaixo, possuo 3 links com uma imagem em cada um deles, que direcionam para um *iframe* logo abaixo. Essas imagens estão em tons de cinza, mas ao passar o mouse sobre elas elas ficam coloridas graças a classe *".passo"*. Porém eu gostaria que o efeito que o hover faz ficasse permanente até que eu clique em outro lugar, é possível fazer isso apenas com html e css?

```
        <a href="passo1.html" target="janela">
            <img id="passo1" class="passo" src="img/passo_color1.png" style="float:left">
        </a>
        <a href="passo2.html" target="janela">
            <img id="passo2" class="passo" src="img/passo_color2.png" style="left: 348px; float:left; position: absolute">
        </a>
        <a href="passo3.html" target="janela">
            <img id="passo3" class="passo" src="img/passo_color3.png" style="left: 685px; float:left; position: absolute">
        </a>
```

Abraços !!

Comment: Diego podes fazer um jsFiddle como exemplo? Assim fica mais fácil de testar e vais ter ajuda mais rápido.

Comment: Cara sou iniciante, não faço ideia do que é JsFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net inclua seus códigos html/css/js (se tiver) nos campos destinados e salve, gerando um link que possa ser compartilhado

Comment: @Sergio eu criaria um evento `onmouseover` na imagem que adicionasse o efeito colorido e outro evento `onclick` no body pra remover todas as classes.

Answer (score 3):

Bem, eis um exemplo do que eu entendi que você quer: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nr6LpLqb/1/)

Não ficou claro pra mim o "outro lugar" que é necessário clicar para que o estado hover saia, então fiz apenas um modelo que mantém o estado hover (usando a propriedade  `transition-delay`) colorindo uma imagem em escala de cinza.

```
.passo {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */     
  transition:0s 180s;
}

.passo:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  transition:0s;
}
```

Referências:

[Escala de cinza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css)

[Manter efeito hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering)

Comment: Aparentemente é isso mesmo. Esse exemplo funciona caso tenha mais imagens?

Comment: Claro: http://jsfiddle.net/nr6LpLqb/2/